# Update datetimepicker with a new date

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using fullcalendar to manage my events and bootstrap modal for update my event.
My problem problem is when I click on new event it doesn't update my datetimepicker field, it keep the old date but for all other field everything is updated.

Here is the script I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
        locale: 'fr'
    });

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,basicDay,listWeek'
        },
        defaultDate: '2017-05-12',
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: <?= $data_json ?>,
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            //moment.locale('fr');

            $('#modalTitle').html(calEvent.title);
            $('#titre_court').val(calEvent.title);
            tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(calEvent.description);

            $('.date_plannification').empty();

            console.log('start >> '+calEvent.start);
            $('.date_plannification').datetimepicker({
                format : "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm",
                date : calEvent.start
            });

            $('#fullCalModal').modal();

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: $('.date_plannification').val(calevent.start);
If you get some value like object, you can format calevent.start and put this into input (datetimepicker) value with val() function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`date()`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date) method to set value to existing datetimepicker, while you can use [`defaultDate`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#defaultdate) option to preset a value when you initialize a datetimepicker.

Your code could be like the following:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
  $('#modalTitle').html(calEvent.title);
  $('#titre_court').val(calEvent.title);
  tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(calEvent.description);

  $('.date_plannification').empty();

  console.log('start >> '+calEvent.start);
  $('.date_plannification').datetimepicker({
    format : "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm",
    defaultDate : calEvent.start
  });

  $('#fullCalModal').modal();

}
```